# Webpack Exclude a specific file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I have this code In my `webpack.config.prod.js` and I was wondering how do I exclude all json except one in a specific path like `src/configs/configs`

```
exclude: [
  /\.html$/,
  /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  /\.css$/,
  /\.json$/,
  /\.bmp$/,
  /\.gif$/,
  /\.jpe?g$/,
  /\.png$/,
],
loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
options: {
  name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
}

...
```

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition), you can do something like this.

```
exclude: {
  test: [
    /\.html$/,
    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    /\.css$/,
    /\.json$/,
    /\.bmp$/,
    /\.gif$/,
    /\.jpe?g$/,
    /\.png$/,
  ],
  exclude: [
    'src/configs/configs/your.json'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15):

To make exclude work I had to escape the dot in the specific file I wanted to exclude. Here's an example of excluding favicon.ico from a general rule and adding a special rule for it:

```
  {
    test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
    exclude: /favicon\.ico$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    },
  },
  // A special rule for favicon.ico to place it into build root directory.
  {
    test: /favicon\.ico$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash:8]',
    },
  },
```