# react js exclude a component of webpack bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created an app with react-create-app, which generated a webpack config. But now, I would like to exclude a component of the bundle webpack because this component contains config info that must be modified. I read a lot about externals and exclude config with webpack but unfortunately none seems to work for me. In my case, here is my src folder:

```
-views
-config
|-ConfigCtl.js
-App.js
...
```

I want to exclude the file ConfigCtl.js. I tried to put this in the webpack.config.dev.js file at the modules.export section:

```
externals: {
    "./src/config/ConfigCtl.js": "ConfigCtl"
  }
```

But the ConfigCtl file is always packed in the bundle... 
Is not a duplicate of other subject. I've tried the solution proposed in this subject but without efficiency...
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack Exclude a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376589/webpack-exclude-a-specific-file)

Comment: I've already tried this solution... but not work and also tried to edit this section :  
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },  I've also read some git forum subjects + subjects : 
reactjs - Exclude specific packages from bundle in Webpack
reactjs - How to exclude a certain file from bundling with Webpack ...
reactjs - Webpack2, how to exclude react and react ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react with webpack go to your webpack config file and in the rule that test for /.js$/ there is a section to exclude dir or files from the bundle.Once this is done the file will be excluded from the bundle.

```
 module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,"./src/config/ConfigCtl.js"
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
```

Comment: I've tried to set like that but without result. File is always packed into the bundle...  
 // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            exclude: paths.appSrc + "/config/ConfigCtl.js",
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },