# Is it possible to avoid bundling the React library using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Is it possible to avoid bundling the React library during the build when using create-react-app? I would rather load it from a CDN. Otherwise, I will have to use WebPack instead, which is alright but I really to use create-react-app as it keeps everything contained and tidy.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to load it from a CDN? If you are using other libraries apart from `react`, `create-react-app` will bundle it in a single `main.js` file with _WebPack_. If you want to use other `npm` packages, letting it all be bundled together is probably the best option.

Comment: Just as mentioned above, I wouldn't recommend this approach, but it definitely is possible. Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very nice tutorial on doing just that here. The idea is simple, to make clever use of the “[rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire)” module which may swap in your own “customized” build configurations to override those in the “react-scripts” module’s default configurations that come with create-react-app.

Here's a link to that [tutorial](https://daveceddia.com/customize-create-react-app-webpack-without-ejecting/).

Within your “customized” build configs you can easily ignore certain files, by adding their pattern/path to the “exclude” stub. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376589/webpack-exclude-a-specific-file) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, that seems the best and only solution to do it in a clean way.