# Webpack conditionally include directory

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I would like to be able to mock my endpoints, and am using a `fixtures` directory, which is currently an asset, so when I intercept calls to certain endpoints, I will instead send a GET to `fixtures/user1.json` for example. I'd like to be able to just import this json file instead, but don't want any extra files included in my bundle in production mode. Is there a way to conditionally include the `fixtures` into my bundle via webpack?

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack Exclude a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376589/webpack-exclude-a-specific-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to update your config file you can condition builds like this:

```js
const config = {
  entry: {
    assets: ...
  },
  output: {
    ...
  },
  module: {
    rules: []
  },
  plugins: [ ... ]
};


module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    // add or change config object for prod builds here
  }

  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    // add or change config object for dev builds here
  }

  return config;
};
```

Next, have a look at: [Webpack Exclude a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376589/webpack-exclude-a-specific-file) on how to use Webpack's **rules.exclude** option. You should be able to then **config.module.rules.push({...exclude stuff...})**  while in production's condition to finally exclude said file(s).

Hope this help!

Comment: ah thanks, that link actually answers what I was looking for, I'll mark this as a duplicate