ESLINT 9: Cannot read config file: eslint.config.mjs. Error: end of the stream or a document separator is expected
generated eslint.config.mjs:
    import globals from "globals";
    import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
    import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";
    
    
    export default [
      {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
      pluginJs.configs.recommended,
      ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
    ];


package.json eslint related packages:

    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint": "^9.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-formatter-summary": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-lit": "^1.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^1.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-wc": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0"


Once I am running eslint on specific files/folders I am able to see the errors, rules / plugins are working. But, when I am getting on the build app stage of the application :
[PluginError: [eslint] Cannot read config file: eslint.config.mjs
Error: end of the stream or a document separator is expected (7:19)

 4 | 
 5 | 
 6 | export default [
 7 |   {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
-----------------------^
 8 |   pluginJs.configs.recommended,
 9 |   ...tseslint.configs.recommended,] {
  plugin: 'webpack-stream',
  showProperties: true,
  showStack: false,
  __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] }
}
[19:04:14] assets by status 9.27 MiB [cached] 3 assets
  

ERROR in [eslint] Cannot read config file: eslint.config.mjs
Error: end of the stream or a document separator is expected (7:19)

 4 | 
 5 | 
 6 | export default [
 7 |   {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
-----------------------^
 8 |   pluginJs.configs.recommended,
 9 |   ...tseslint.configs.recommended,

Should there be any updates in Webpack config (for webpack eslint config) with this newest 9th ESLint version?
Configuration for webpack eslint config:
    new ESLintPlugin({
    quiet: true,
    failOnError: true,
    outputReport: true,
    overrideConfigFile: join(dirname, 'eslint.config.mjs'),
    exclude: [
      `model`,
      `dist`,
      `node_modules`,
      `buildlocales`
    ]
  }),


Did I get this straight, eslint is working correctly but not the build? You need to make sure that the eslint.config.mjs file is not handled during build, it is not part of the application. You can exclude files in your webpack build like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380045/5470544

@JSONDerulo nice nickname:) I actually need my build to break on ESLint error, adding my configuration to the question

@JSONDerulo Yes, ESLint is working correctly but during the build, it's breaking on some kind of a parsing error for config ESLint file

Adding the line configType: 'flat' to Webpack ESLintPlugin configs did the trick for me (requested earlier but with a syntax error – remember to use camelCase)

Try adding configtype: "flat" to your webpack eslint plugin. Per the docs, the default is still the .eslintrc.json file.
I was throwing the same error but this worked for my trivial test.
From the eslint-webpack-plugin docs
